# Launch Activity on AlarmManager event from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have am alarm manager through which i set a time to trigger on it by providing a broadcast receiver, `onReceive` method of broadcast receiver calls successfully but any idea how to launch app from `onReceive` if app is not running in foreground?

**Menifest**

```
<receiver
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1000,intent,0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeInMillis,pendingIntent);
```

Kindly help
Thanks

Comment: You cannot launch an activity from the background on modern versions of Android. Please use a high-priority `Notification` instead.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for a prompt reply, what do you suggest to use if I want to play a scheduled music stream automatically?

Secondly , as you suggested to use high periority notification , will it be a local notification or a push notification and can I launch an a activity from a push notification? Thanks

Comment: "what do you suggest to use if I want to play a scheduled music stream automatically?" -- if it something akin to a ringtone, you could perhaps tie it directly to the `Notification`. If it is something longer, have a `Notification` provide the UI for a foreground `Service` that plays the stream. "will it be a local notification or a push notification" -- `Notification` on Android refers to what I suppose you mean by "local notification". "can I launch an a activity from a push notification?" -- no.

Comment: It is basically a radio music stream using exoplayer , what we need is user set a time on which he want it to play , and when that time comes stream start playing automatically . Two things in my mind either background or foreground service.

Answer (score 1):

> It is basically a radio music stream using exoplayer , what we need is user set a time on which he want it to play , and when that time comes stream start playing automatically .

A background service will only run for one minute on Android 8.0+. For a music player, you will want a foreground service, where the associated `Notification` gives the user playback controls (e.g., pause, resume, stop).

Comment: Thanks, I would need little more help, My requirement is to show a notification on broadcast receive method and that notification can stream a music stream. Music stream method is written in main activity , but when the onReceive of broadcast receiver is called at that time no method of main activity is callable because its not in foreground. Need help, thanks

Comment: @AliAkram: "Music stream method is written in main activity" -- that will not work. You will need to move the music stream logic to some singleton that you can control from the activity (when it is around), from the foreground service (when it is around), or perhaps from broadcasts from the `Notification` (when it is around).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use [workManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)
Also, Brodcastreciver has limits on different android versions [doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)